# How can I stream/record my iOS device to MacOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, quicktime, webcam

I'm thinking about making some videos that will need to be recorded from my iPhone and using them in a common, Twitch-like setup where the phone's display is in one region, and a webcam, or other graphics, are displayed around the iOS stream.  I've read that others partially achieve this by using QuickTime Pro to record.  QuickTime Pro integrated a feature where you could start recording from a connected iOS device and that would work perfectly for my scenario.

But this isn't the answer.  I don't have QuickTime Pro, so I went to see about purchasing a license.  Googling "QuickTime Pro" with a couple other modifiers hasn't shown me anything of use and even the buy links from Apples own page seem to be broken.

On the Apple support forums, I saw another user ask where to get a key for QT Pro, and someone responded that a security flaw was found in the Windows version and that Apple has since stopped selling licenses.

So, what's the best alternative?  Specifically, is there an Apple-branded alternative that will allow me to stream/record from my iOS device to my macOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to record videos from your iPhone, you can use the normal QuickTime Player to achieve that.

Just connect your iPhone to your Mac, open QuickTime Player and follow the following steps:

1. Click on 'File' in the menu
2. Select 'New Movie Recording'
3. Click on the small downward-pointing arrow beside the record button

   - [image: Image 1]
4. Click on your phone's name under 'Camera'

If you want to record the sound from your iPhone, select your phone's name under 'Microphone' too. Else it will record from your Mac's microphone.

Comment: Actually, I found out the bigger issue.  I have QT 7, and that's because QT 10 comes with an extra MacOS update that I manually have to download and install.  I need to restart my PC and I can do this.  Still, I think this will be the answer.  Let me restart and give this a try.

Comment: @RLH Great, did this work?